# Edit excel record in Userform

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I would like to edit my table records using a userform. However, the code below only works for the first row (I have no idea why). Can you please help me modify my code so that it will work to whatever row I would like to modify? I always get the error "Type Mismatch" and then points me in this code "WriteRow = Application.Match(ABnum, ABrng, 0)"

This is my code so far:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ABnum As String
Dim ABrng As Range
Dim WriteRow As Long

Sheets("CDP DATABASE").Select
With ActiveSheet
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set ABrng = .Range("B7:B" & LastRow)
ABnum = txtemn.Value
WriteRow = Application.Match(ABnum, ABrng, 0)
Cells(WriteRow, 1).Select
End With

With ActiveCell
.Offset(0, 1).Value = txtemn.Value
.Offset(0, 2).Value = txtcode.Value
.Offset(0, 3).Value = txttype.Value
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Also, I would like to force my user to only use the userforms to add and edit records. I've tried protecting the sheet, but with this method I'm unable to edit or add anything using forms. Please help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you're using the wrong tool. Excel is not a GUI designer. The closest thing to that is Access.

Comment: @DanielB, I understand, however, the client wants it on excel. So I'm doing what I can to create this using excel. I'm almost there, just need to have my code work on any row on my table. I hope you, or someone can help me. Thank you

Comment: can someone help me? :(